# How do I remove a character from the replacement pattern?

Tags: views

In view I call the field *field_store_car_model*

**settings of this field:**

formatter: link
result URL is:`veyron-164`

So far as expected.

---

But I need this URL: `vehicles/veyron-164`.
Because of this I have to rewrite the link.

I check rewrite result, format is plain text, I write in the field `vehicle/[field_store_car_model]`

**Result here:** `vehicles/veyron-16.4`.

Now I have this punctuation in the URL! where does the decimal point come from?
From my vocab because view grabs the term BEFORE pathauto cleans it up.

So how can I **get rid of the decimal point**?
I am sure there is some PHP but WHERE I have to put the PHP code?

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure I completely understand your question. But I'm guessing this is what you're looking for.

- In Views, under FIELDS, click on the name of your field
- Click on REWRITE RESULTS
- Enable Output this field as a link
- In Link path, insert something like **vehicles/[field_store_car_model]**, where
  [field_store_car_model] is one of the available Replacement patterns.

Hope this helps.

Comment: hello Bisonbleu, i have rewritten my question, hopefully you undestand it now the right way. maybe an idea? kind regards

Comment: Oh, I understand now. Although it's never a good idea to store php in the DB, you could try with the [Views PHP](http://drupal.org/project/views_php) module.

Comment: hi! yes i came across this module and i am aware of not to store php in the database. therefor i googling how to use the views api. any hints in this direction?

Comment: Another idea. You could add a field to your taxonomy vocab called 'no dot name' into which you would insert 'veyron-164'. Then in views, use that field's replacement pattern in the Rewrite result.

Comment: *hehe yea this came also to my mind. i wont do it because, i dont like the idea to do work twice. one field for the display name and one field for the internal handling.

i try a solution that modifies the data before the view is rendered or something.

Comment: You could use computed_field to automatically populate the 'no dot name' field.

Comment: ok played arrounf with the computed field. but i just get static values with this: $entity_field[0]['value'] = "here my value";

how can i get the value of the term reference field *field_store_car_model* in that computed field.

i have tried:
$entity_field[0]['value'] = $entity->field__store_car_model[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']

but that dont work. any idea?

Comment: ok, found something:
$entity_field[0]['value'] = taxonomy_term_title(taxonomy_term_load($entity->field__store_car_model['und'][0]['tid']));

Question: possible to load her the alias that pathauto created?